# Mysql query from table 2 using value from table 1

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I want to search both table with all the records for cid 23 here

Total is table1-cid:23&w_id:1+2->(500+300),
Advance is table1-cid:23&w_id:1+2(100+100)+table 2-w_id:1+2(100+100+100+150)
Pending is Total-Advance

Tried using below query to display last table in pic with no luck.

```
SELECT  E.cid, SUM(E.total) as Total, SUM(E.advance)as Advance, (SUM(E.total)-SUM(E.advance)- SUM(R.advance)) as Pending
        FROM table1 AS E 
        LEFT JOIN table2 R ON E.w_id=R.w_id
        WHERE (E.cid =23)
```

Comment: Our first question:  What do you want to get???  Describe what do you want to get.  Don't just dump query and expect us to somehow understand what you're trying to do, and expect us to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best query I've done but I obtain the result you want:

wwtest1 = table-1 , wwtest2 = table 2.

```
SELECT w1.cid AS cid, 
(SELECT SUM(total) FROM wwtest WHERE cid = 23) AS total, 
((SELECT SUM(advance) FROM wwtest WHERE cid = 23) + (SELECT SUM(advance) FROM wwtest2))  AS advance,
((SELECT SUM(total) FROM wwtest WHERE cid = 23) - ((SELECT SUM(advance) FROM wwtest WHERE cid = 23) + (SELECT SUM(advance) FROM wwtest2))) AS pending
FROM wwtest w1
WHERE w1.cid = 23 GROUP BY w1.cid;
```